# The built-in functions are not working. I tried everything to run this code but seems like the only problem would be the built-in funcitons

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    'First half of 2019' AS date_range,
    SUM(invoice_total) AS total_sales,
    SUM(payment_total) AS total_payments,
    (total_sales - total_payments) AS what_we_expect
FROM invoices
WHERE invoice_date 
    BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-06-30'
```

I tried everything to make this code run but I could not find any problems. The only thing I could think of is the built-in functions. Usually every keyword that is from SQL is blue but the built-in functions dont turn blue. My guess is that the program doesnt detect that as built-in functions. Am i missing something here?

[image: SCHEMAS]

Comment: You can't reference a column alias defined in the same SELECT clause.

Comment: Instead  do `SUM(invoice_total) - SUM(payment_total) AS what_we_expect`.